# Deploy Zend Application to the cloud

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud-hosting

Was wondering if anyone out there has any experience in deploying a Zend community app to the cloud (e.g. AWS or similar)?

I'm new to cloud hosting having always been fortunate enough in the past to work for folks who have dedicated servers, my main concern (non-zend specific) is how you manage resilience at the database level?  FOr example I would in a traditional setup have 2 boxes running the DB (Mysql) in Master/Slave mode with the master replicating to the slave.  Assuming any HD failure of the Master I could swap the DB connection over from the Master to the slave and rebuild master at a later point?  is this done differently in the cloud?

Any help/pointers greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of cloud service that you use. If you're using AWS to get your own virtual machine ( Amazon EC2 ) then it's basically the same as having a dedicated server and you can keep a master slave setup and work them much the same way.

However, if you plan on using Amazon's cloud database service ( Amazon Simple DB ) then you don't have to worry about masters and slaves since Amazon does this for you and makes sure that you always have access to your data. The only thing is that it's in beta.

One of the points of the cloud is to take your mind off the hardware. Amazon worries about that.

You might still want to have two virtual machines in case amazon is doing maintenance that might cause your vm to become unavailable, however, Amazon stresses that it would be highly available and never go down really, so long as you pay.

Comment: Thanks - so you suggest running one or 2 dedicated instances for DB's and scale the apps?

Comment: Yes, if you're running virtual dedicated servers that is what you can/should do. Since they are basically like physical machines, and therefore independent of each other, they can crash just like any other machine.